# Where to submit Google Gadgets for Blogger?

Tags: blogger, google-gadget, igoogle

I am a blogger user and I have seen a lot of useful gadgets in the Blogger gadget directory to integrate with my blog. Not too long ago I decided to write my own gadgets to integrate them with my blog.

Throughout the Google Gadgets API docs I find everywhere links to www.google.com/ig/submit to submit gadgets, however, that link takes me to a blog saying igoogle is shutting down on November 2013. I could not find any other link for submitting gadgets to Google.

I understand that after Novermber 2013 gadgets will not longer be accepted for integration with igoogle, but does it mean the same when it comes to Blogger ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried the submit link at the bottom of 
[Gadgets for Blogger](https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/gadgets/gadgets_for_blogger) page in Google Developers site?

Comment: That link I had not tried. It works! They should update the docs to point to that link.

Answer (score 1):

This is the page for upload..

https://www.blogger.com/gadget-submit.g